# In the problem of laminar flow through a very thin annulus, I encountered a problem in regards to long division

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$w(\frac{8\mu L}{\pi (P_0 - P_L)R^4\rho}) = (1-(1-\epsilon)^4) + \frac{(1-(1-\epsilon)^2}{ln(1-\epsilon)}$

After expanding the terms on the right-hand side and writing a 4 term Taylor Series expansion for $ln(1-\epsilon)$, we get on the RHS

$=(4\epsilon - 6\epsilon^2 + 4\epsilon^3 - \epsilon^3) - \frac{4\epsilon^3 - 4\epsilon^3 + \epsilon^4}{\epsilon + (1/2)\epsilon^2 + (1/3)\epsilon^3 + (1/4)\epsilon^4 + ...}$

After a long division is performed, the answer is obtained. I am unable to obtain the 4th order polynomial that results. I request help only on this single step.

Comment: Please, confirm expression in numerator of second term RHS, both expressions, and also exponent in first parenthesis of second line ( $- \epsilon^3$ or $- \epsilon^4$?).